# Efficient way to create pages from multiple similar type links

Tags: dynamic, hyperlink, html

I have a page where there are about 30 links and those links would have similar page except for a few contents changed(there is also pictuures). Now is there an efficient way to do that without repeating the codes and repeated nestings of the codes. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using plain HTML you won't be able to do this.

The most straightforward way to do it, I think, is using server-side scripting to implement a rendering template. You could then have a default "main" template with everything those 30 pages have in common and then in each of those pages use the main template and load the custom content.

So if you want to modify something in the main template you'd only have to modify the `main.html` (or whatever you called it) page and not each of the 30 pages.

[**See this.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/95027/2612112)